# How to debug an Ada program?

Tags: ada

I did the problem and when I try to compile it said that identifier expected but I did all right.

```
with.Ada.TexT_IO;use Ada.Text_IO;
Procedure Isort1 is

  type node;
  type link is access node;
  type node  is
        record
        value:integer;
        rest:Character;
        next:link;
        end record;

        package IntIO is new Ada.Text_IO.Integer_IO(integer);use IntIO;

        int:integer;
        l:link;
        pt:array(1..100)of link;
        ch:character;

begin
   for i in 1..10 loop pt(i):=null;
   end loop;
   loop
      put("put an integer key  (1 thru 10),99 to stop ");
      get(int);
      exit when int=99;
      put("enter the other info,1 char ");
      get(ch);
      pt(int):= new node'(int,ch,pt(int));
   end loop;

   for i in 1..10 loop
   i:=pt(i);
   while I /=null loop
      put(I.value);
      put("... ");
      put(I.rest);
      new_line;
      I:=I.next;
      end loop;
  end loop;
end Isort1;
```

Comment: Your first line has an extra period. It should read `with Ada.Text_IO;`  not `with.Ada.Text_IO;`

Comment: You cannot modify the control variable of a for loop within the for loop.
"for i in 1..10 loop i := pt(i)" is illegal. The program is looking for a variable on the left hand side of the assignment. Within the loop body identifier 'i' is immutable.

Comment: What errors do you get? What output did you get that you are not expecting?

Answer (score 3):

Your assumption that you "did all right" is clearly wrong. 
It appears that you are learning Ada after knowing some other programming language. You appear to be mixing ideas from other language(s) into your Ada code.

Let's organize and indent your code first.

```
with.Ada.TexT_IO;use Ada.Text_IO;
Procedure Isort1 is

  type node;
  type link is access node;
  type node  is
        record
        value:integer;
        rest:Character;
        next:link;
        end record;

        package IntIO is new Ada.Text_IO.Integer_IO(integer);use IntIO;

        int:integer;
        l:link;
        pt:array(1..100)of link;
        ch:character;

begin
   for i in 1..10 loop pt(i):=null;
   end loop;
   loop
      put("put an integer key  (1 thru 10),99 to stop ");
      get(int);
      exit when int=99;
      put("enter the other info,1 char ");
      get(ch);
      pt(int):= new node'(int,ch,pt(int));
   end loop;

   for i in 1..10 loop
   i:=pt(i);
   while I /=null loop
      put(I.value);
      put("... ");
      put(I.rest);
      new_line;
      I:=I.next;
      end loop;
  end loop;
end Isort1;
```

Your first line begins with "with.Ada.TexT_IO;". It should say "with Ada.Text_I0;". Capitalization differences are not the problem. The problem is the period '.' following the reserved word "with".

Once that problem is fixed the compiler will tell you that you have an error in the line containing

```
i:=pt(i);
```

The error messages from the compiler are shown in the screen capture below.
[image: GNAT builder screen capture]

It appears that you want the variable I to contain an instance of type node, but variable I is never declared and is never assigned a value.